# Porcupine wake up word detection with text to speech

Tags: android, kotlin, text-to-speech

I'm building an android app which must respond in the this way
When I say the wake up word and it gets detected by Porcupine wake up word engine the app sould convert a text I have provided to speech using the built in Text to speech API and if I say the wake up word while the text to speech is still speaking the text to speech must stop.

Right now I have set up the porcupine wake up word engine and text to speech so when I say the wake up word for the first time the text to speech runs normally but if I say the wake up word while text to speech is speaking the Porcupine engine doesn't detect the wake up word unless I reduce the volume to around 25 : 30 %

So is there a way to fix this so that even if the text to speech is speaking the moment I say the wake up word it stops.
Any methods like speaker isolation or something.